# JSTL for each arraylist with dropdown list in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, drop-down-menu, jstl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn4rx.png)First of all, I know there are a few threads about this, but none of those could solve my issue.

I am trying to use JSTL in JSP. I want to load values in a dropdown list from a arraylist. And when using the for each function, it does not work. I can get the values of the arraylist if I print it out as a list, but can't print them out one by one.

```
                   <select name="database1">
                        <option selected="selected"  value="Select ID">Select ID</option>
                        <c:forEach var="databaseValue" items="${databaseList}" >
                            <option value="${databaseList}">
                                ${databaseList}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

This work, it prints out the whole list in one option in the dropdown menu.

```
                        <select name="database1">
                        <c:forEach items="${databaseList}" var="databaseValue">
                            <option value="${databaseValue}">
                                ${databaseValue}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

This does not work.

Any ideas why?

Edit:

Here is the part of the servlet code that creates and sends the arraylist:

```
            ArrayList<String> databaseArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            databaseArrayList.add("red");
            databaseArrayList.add("orange");
            databaseArrayList.add("yellow");
            databaseArrayList.add("green");
            databaseArrayList.add("blue");

            System.out.println("Adding values");

            request.setAttribute("databaseList", databaseArrayList); //categorylist is an arraylist      contains object of class category  
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("requestData.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

[Here is the output in the dropdown menus][2]

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn4rx.png)

Comment: what error message or output did you get?

Comment: @MinjunYu There are no errors generated

Comment: Then what output did you get? Zero option? unreadable options?

Comment: Please see the picture uploaded. The first one is the output if I access a specific item in the arraylist. The 2nd one is for the first code. And the last one is for the 2nd piece of code.

Comment: Did you include the jstl taglab for "c:" tags in your jsp file? like `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: @MinjunYu Ahhh, dammit. That was the issue. Thank you :)